# Any Ubuntu or 3rd party extensions for touchscreen?

Tags: 15.10, touchscreen

My laptop has a touchscreen.  Recently I installed a partition Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10  -- I noticed touch behaves differently between the two operating systems.

Touchscreen on my windows machine is very sensitive.  I like being able to use my two fingers to expand sections of text or to scroll quickly down a page.  The Ubuntu touch screen does not do this.

Ubuntu - being open source - can't always be current (but usually catches up).  Are there any extensions I can download to enable these features?

Answer (score 0):

Touchscreen is already supported by Ubuntu. The [Multitouch Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch#Supported_Gestures) page lists the supported gestures in Unity.

The problem you are describing is that the applications you are using don't support touch screens.

For example, other than the available Unity gestures, Google Chrome has support for touch screens. For instance, you can pinch to zoom and scroll through the page with your fingers (you can find the touch settings if you go to `chrome://flags/#touch-events` in Chrome), [while Firefox doesn't support touch screens on Linux yet](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=711711).

Another example is the image viewer which also has touch support. You can pinch to zoom, swipe left or right to go the next or previous image (or scroll through the image when it is not set).